# Xcode 9 - Trying to animate the UIView twice

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiviewanimation

I am trying to animate a button to tilt to the left by pi/5 and then by the right by the same amount so it goes back to its original position (I'm trying to make the button appear as if it's shaking)

However, Xcode cuts out the animation as it realizes that the button overall doesn't change the angle. Heres the current code - if anyone would have any suggestions to animate the button to shake back and forth it would really appreciate.

```
for i in 0...8 {

if pressedArray[i] == true {

    self.panlButtons[i].backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations:{

        self.panlButtons[i].backgroundColor = self.wrongColour
        self.panlButtons[i].transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / -5)

    })


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations:{

        self.panlButtons[i].backgroundColor = self.wrongColour
        self.panlButtons[i].transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 5)

    }, completion: { finished in


        self.panlButtons[i].backgroundColor = self.notPressedColour

    })
```

Code explanation:
pressedArray[] is an array of Bools indicating which button is pressed
panlButtons[] is an array of the buttons
The for loop from 0-8 is because there are only 8 buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move next animation in the completion of first animation, Like below

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations:{
    self.panlButtons[i].backgroundColor = self.wrongColour
    self.panlButtons[i].transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / -5)
}, completion: {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations:{
        self.panlButtons[i].backgroundColor = self.wrongColour
        self.panlButtons[i].transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 5)
    }, completion: { finished in
        self.panlButtons[i].backgroundColor = self.notPressedColour
    })
})
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks a lot!